# How we can detect firewall or sonicwall redirect for our normal request in iOS devices ?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking-2, nsurlrequest, alamofire

So here is the question

Many times you start your app and and your first API request fails and you realize that even though you're connected through internet You need to login in to Your office' or home network's firewall or sonicwall and login there

So you need to open safari and open your sonicwall page and login there and come back to our app and start it again.

I want my app to detect the same and show the the redirected html page in UIWebView and once the authintication finishes i want to execute the original request withing my app

My question is

**1> Is it possible ?**

**2> If yes how can i achieve it ?**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the same captive portal probe URLs that Apple uses in iOS Safari, for maximum compatibility.  If those URLs return 200, you shouldn't be behind a (good) captive portal, assuming I'm remembering the details correctly.

You can beef that up further by using reachability APIs to detect network changes, and probing that URL, along with Google's generate_204 URL.  And in some places, you'll find Google blocked (China, IIRC), in which case you might also consider a URL with a known, predictable, machine-validateable value, such as Apple's root certificate URL.  :-)

When the user signs in, you should get another reachability change event, at which point at least one of your captive portal probes will succeed, and you can reissue any outstanding requests.

Comment: How would i know the destination URL to which it's being redirected ?

Comment: When you detect that you're behind a captive portal, do a normal URL load request for some random URL (ideally something that isn't likely to be in the DNS cache) with either NSURLConnection or NSURLSession.  Specify a delegate, and implement the redirect handling method.  Grab the URL, and send the user off to Safari.  Or if you're doing requests anyway, just implement the redirect handling method, and if you see a URL that doesn't make sense (i.e. a redirect to a local IP address), assume that you're behind a captive portal, and send the user to Safari.